# php while loop where functions are ran based on time of day

Tags: php

I have created two functions in a separate php file and want them to run over and over.

After `function A` completes, I want it to compare the current time, relative to the last time `function B` ran, and if more than 24hrs has elapsed (or whatever value I set it to), it runs `function B`, resets the next time for when it should be trigger to run, and continues to run `function A`. They need to run separately and not parallel since values altered in `function A` will affect `function B` and thus need to be separate. The ideal scenario is I have a `config.php` file where I set the time delay (in hours), but I can sort that out later!

I am stumped on how to get this `while(true){}` loop organized... any ideas?

Comment: If you are using Linux you want to look into running them as crons.
https://www.linux.com/learn/scheduling-magic-intro-cron-linux

Comment: Yes, CRONs and some sort of data persistence such as flat files or database entries.

Comment: @TheDude I thought of crons initially, but I would like to run the while true loop in a screen on linux so I can see their outputs at any given time...

Comment: you can output to custom log file and see it where you need, but cron job still the best option.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Regardless of whether you end up doing it this way (because I think the comments about cron make some good points, and there are some other issues you may run into with a continuously running PHP script like this) here's a basic logic for executing the alternate function based on a defined delay.

```
// define the delay and initialize the timestamp
$delay = 86400;        // 24 hours, for example
$last_time = time();

while (true) {
    functionA();
    // the next time functionB should execute is the timestamp for the last run + the delay
    if (time() > $last_time + $delay) {
        functionB();
        $last_time = time();   // reset the timestamp
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Would something of this nature be similar to what you're looking for?

```
while ($time > 13 && $time < 21)
```

You could have flags involved in each function as well. If a boolean flag is fired and is = 1, then continue on?